# fetching email address from facebook

Tags: playframework

finally I am able to connect to the facebook through fg graph, its cool, and I appreciate all you help.
but now I am trying to fetch all the friends list and their related email address, but I can only get name and id. Can we do something to fetch all the email address.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to fetch your friends EMail address.